# como fazer um contador de dias por status no mantis?

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer um contador de dias, no qual conta separadamente cada estado em que o *bug* está por exemplo: 20 dias no primeiro estado e quando mudamos para o segundo, está em 0, pois nunca foi mudado para esse estado

Eu fiz algumas linhas de código, mas não está funcionando, está apenas contando a partir da última vez em que o bug foi mudado até a data de hoje
eu estou pensando em pegar as datas de modificação e subtrair com as datas em que aquele bug foi mudado do primeiro estado para outro e com a data em que o bug foi mudado de outro estado para o primeiro e ir somando.

```
 switch ($status_day){
        case 10:
        $day_open;
        $querya = "select * from mantis_bug_history_table where bug_id=". db_param();
        $oloco = db_query_bound ($querya, array ($id_bug));
        $rowa = db_fetch_array ($oloco);
        if($day_open='') {

              $queryyy = "select date_modified from mantis_bug_history_table where field_name='' and bug_id=". db_param() ." order by date_modified limit 1";
              db_query_bound ($queryyy, array ($id_bug));
              break;
        }
        $queryy = "select date_modified from mantis_bug_history_table where bug_id=" . db_param() . " and new_value=10 order by date_modified DESC";
        $calculo = db_query_bound ($queryy, array ($id_bug));
        $rowww = db_fetch_array ($calculo);
        $datacriadas = date ("Y-m-d ", $rowww['date_modified']);
        $comecos = new DateTime ($datacriadas);
        $date = date("Y-m-d");
        $fimm = new DateTime ($date);
        $interval = $comecos->diff($fimm);
        $day_open = $interval->format("%a");
        $queria = mysql_query("select COUNT(*) from mantis_bug_history_table where bug_id=$id_bug and new_value=10");
        $tempoinicio = mysql_fetch_array ($queria);
        $rowinicio = $tempoinicio['COUNT(*)'];
        $querio = mysql_query("select COUNT(*) from mantis_bug_history_table where bug_id=$id_bug and old_value=10");
        $tempofinal = mysql_fetch_array ($querio);
        $rowfinal = $tempofinal['COUNT(*)'];
        for( $i = 0;$i<=$rowinicio or $i<=$rowfinal;$i++) {
            echo $rowinicio;
            $datacriadas = date ("Y-m-d ", $tempoinicio['date_modified']);
            $comecos = new DateTime ($datacriadas);
            $date = date ("Y-m-d ", $tempofinal['date_modified']);
            $fimm = new DateTime ($date);
            $interval = $fimm->diff($comecos);
            $day_ope = $interval->format("%a");
            $day_open = $day_ope + $day_open;
         }
         $sqle = "UPDATE $string_table  t1 INNER JOIN mantis_custom_field_table t2 ON (t1.field_id = t2.id) SET value=$day_open WHERE t2.name='DiasStatus' AND t1.bug_id=$id_bug";
         break;
        }
```